# Powershell Get-Content cmdlet result with -contains operator

Tags: powershell

I wish to select some results of `Get-ChildItem` if the `Name` property is contained in a collection of names retrived from a text file using `Get-Content`.

I was trying with a command like this:

```
$filter = Get-Content 'filter.txt'
gci |? Name -In $filter | select FullName
```

But this don't works. I suppose this is related with reference equality comparison, i.e. `-In` or `-Contains` are checking if `$filter` (which is an `object[]`) contains exactly the same instance of the string returned by the `Name` property.

Even casting `$filter` to `string[]` don't work, nor manipulation with `@()` `,`.

There is a simple way to obtains what i need?

Comment: Works fine for me. I assume names in the file have corresponding objects in the output of gci. Does filter.txt contains names in the format of filename.ext? Also make sure no trailing spaces exist after the file name.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell v2 or earlier? I don't think the notation `? Property -In Array` is supported prior to PowerShell v3. Try `? { $filter -contains $_.Name }` instead. If that doesn't work: please provide sample filter content and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: You're correct that -In is looking for an exact match.  Are you sure there's no trailing whitespace in the entries in yor list?

Comment: Thansk for your answer. And Yes, the problem are the trailing spaces at end of each line in my file `filter.txt`. This file was produced by a `gci [...] | ft Name | Out-File 'filter.txt`. Why `Out-File` add these spaces? How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: At present, replacing `| ft Name` or `| select Name` with `|% { $_.Name }` appear the best workaround.